# Start a class inside a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to run a simple piece of RMI code to be implemented in a larger project sooner. But when I put my server inside a jar and try to start it, I get an error; could not find class.
The command i used is `java -cp myClassPath -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\help\me\pls package-name.Logger`
So I'm pretty sure my issue is with the very last part, how do i point to the class file insider a jar file?

Comment: RMI has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I put my server inside a jar and try to start it, I get an error; could not find class. The command i used is `java -cp myClassPath -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\help\me\pls package-name.Logger.`

There is nowhere here where you've tried to start a JAR file. You haven't even mentioned it on the command line.

The correct way to start a JAR file is to include a manifest with a `Main- Class` attribute, a `Class-Path` attribute if there are other JARs that this one depends on, and the command line

```
java -jar MyJar.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:C:\help\me\pls
```